# Docker, running multiple container (elasticsearch)

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I'm running one elasticsearch with

```
version: '3'

services:
 elasticsearch:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - MEM=${MEM}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_DEV}
      - CLUSTER_NAME=${CLUSTER_NAME_DEV}
      - ENV=${ENV_DEV}
  container_name: elasticsearch
  network_mode: host
  environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
  volumes:
   - /var/lib/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
 logstash:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/logstash/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_DEV}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_DEV}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST_DEV}
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME_DEV}
      - ENV=${ENV_DEV}
  container_name: logstash
  network_mode: host
  volumes:
   - /opt/logstash/data:/usr/share/logstash/data
  dns:
   -  192.168.1.1  # IP necessary to connect to a database instance external to where the server in which the container is running
 kibana:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/kibana/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_DEV}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_DEV}
  container_name: kibana
  depends_on:
   - elasticsearch
  network_mode: host
 nginx:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/nginx/Dockerfile
    args:
      - KIBANA_HOST=${KIBANA_HOST_DEV}
      - KIBANA_PORT=${KIBANA_PORT_DEV}
  container_name: nginx
  network_mode: host
  depends_on:
   - kibana
 apm:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/apm/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_DEV}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_DEV}
      - APM_PORT=${APM_PORT_DEV}
  container_name: apm
  depends_on:
   - elasticsearch
  network_mode: host
```

(I think this one uses host's `/var/lib/elasticsearch` when container access `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` and the data is persisted in the `/var/lib/elasticsearch` of the host)

Another one with

```
version: '3'

services:
 elasticsearch-search:
  restart: always
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/elasticsearch/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_SEARCH_DEV}
      - MEM=${MEM_SEARCH}
      - CLUSTER_NAME=${CLUSTER_NAME_SEARCH_DEV}
      - ENV=${ENV_DEV}
  container_name: elasticsearch-search
  network_mode: host
  environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
  volumes:
   - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
   - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536
 kibana:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/kibana/Dockerfile
    args:
      - VERSION=${VERSION}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST_SEARCH_DEV}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_SEARCH_DEV}
  container_name: kibana-search
  depends_on:
   - elasticsearch-search
  network_mode: host
  volumes:
   - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
   - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
  data:
```

(I'm not sure how this one works out, but I guess docker provides persistant storage that can be accessed via `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` from container)

When I run them at the same time, I expect the two elasticsearch uses separate data. but it seems they are interfering with each other.

I have a kibana running which looks at the first ES.

When I run the first ES alone, I can see the data , but as soon as I run the second ES, there's nothing, no index-pattern, no dashboard.

What am I misunderstanding?

.env

```
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_DEV=29200
ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_SEARCH_DEV=29300
```

Comment: can you provide the entire content of your compose file in both the case, also how you know they are interfering?

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Amit I added the compose file, and why I think they are interfering

Comment: In the second file there should be a top-level `volumes:` section with a `data:` block within it; that is important to the question.

Comment: @DavidMaze oh yes, I have it on my compose file, missed that part when copying it.

Comment: In the second example where you're storing data in a named volume, how do you expect the data to get in there?  (It seems like you're seeing what you expect, that the two ES installations have data stores isolated from each other.)

Answer (score 1):

most probably something is wrong with your docker-compose in term of `volumes:` sections.

second example has this at the top

```
volumes:
   - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

and this at the bottom:

```
volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    - data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

which means that at least two separate container have binding to the same local folder `data`. which is definitely way to see strange things, because something inside of those containers (ES is one of those) will try to recreate data storage hierarchy in hosts `data` folder.

can you just try defining volumes for first ES as:

```
volumes:
   - ./data/es1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

and for second one as:

```
volumes:
   - ./data/es2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

just make sure that `./data/es1` and `./data/es2` folders are there on your host before doing `docker-compose up`.

or you can post whole `docker-compose.yml` file so we can say what is wrong with it...

Comment: i fixed the op.. the `volumes:` at the top was mean to be a `snippet summary` of docker-compose which follows.

Comment: in this case `elasticsearch` service and `elasticsearch-search` doesn't have conflict on drive. and they should be working at the same time just fine. (assuming your project is not located inside of `/var/lib/elasticsearch`, that is why i would recommend  full path for second as well instead of `data`)

ALSO i don't see you are exposing ports
 ```
ports:
      - 27017:27017
```
which should be different port of host fo second ES. otherwise it will fail to start...

Comment: sorry, ES ports are `ports: - 9200:9200`

Comment: I copied the full docker-compose.. sorry should have done it sooner.

Comment: now i see, volumes on top level are designed to be common place among multiple services.
So you have two options 1) - define two volumes as `dataes1` and `dataes2` and change your services to use them. or 2) - mount 2 host separate path instead of defined loume `data`
here is a doc
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: first docker-compose doesn't have `data:` volumes, the first one uses host path.. I'm using host path because I don't quite understand the `volume` section and worry if i might lose it.  why does `dataes1` and `host-path` interfere each other , I still don't understand